# Shower that gives water in portions

Tags: shower, valve

Could you please advise how is it called when shower gives just a portion of water like for 10 seconds and then stops until you push the big button again. They often have such showers in public places to save water like in swimming pool etc. I need to buy something that would do the same - do I need to buy some automatic mixer valse or how is t called? I don't need it to be sensor triggered or infrared. Just by manually pushing the "button".

Thanks!!!

Comment: A metering, or self-closing valve. See https://www.google.com/search?q=metering+shower+valve